# jquery ui css does not appear when changes from display:none to display:inline

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dynamic-content

High everyone,

In my web-based app, I have a div that is usually `display:none` so that it is hidden and doesn't take up any space.  When something happens, I want the div to appear with the styling for the class `ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all` and i will put in some dynamic content.  So i give this hidden div these classes initially.  The problem is when I show the div with some dynamic content, the styling for the classes i just mentioned is not there.

See this fiddle which illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qR8gK/

The desired outcome is the div that appears when you click the button has the same styling as the one that is visible initially.  Does anyone know how I can do this??

Thanks!

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/qR8gK/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `show()` method to make it visible.

```
$('#a').button().click(function() {
    $('#dynamic').html('<p>some dynamic content</p>').show();
});​
```

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/qR8gK/16/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.show()` instead of manually setting the css display setting.

```
$('#a').button().click(function() {
    $('#dynamic').show().html('<p>some dynamic content</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem in your code was because of the paragraph tag. Remove the `<p>` and try.

```
$('#a').button().click(function() {
    $('#dynamic').css('display', 'inline').html('some dynamic content');
});​
```

sample : http://jsfiddle.net/qR8gK/19/